# EditText in recyclerview is covered by keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

My fragment layout file is as follows

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- Top card -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/new_store_visit_cv_top_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/d8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/d0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/d0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="4.5"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:fontFamily="@font/texgyreheros_regular"
            android:lines="@integer/one"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/d16dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/d10dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/d14dp"
            android:text="@string/in_progress_store_visit"
            android:textSize="@dimen/d16sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_store_visit_ib_compare"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/d0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="@dimen/d10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_compare" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/d0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"
            android:background="@color/pinkish_grey" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/new_store_visit_ib_share"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/d0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:padding="@dimen/d10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/new_store_visit_bt_submit"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/d0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/d30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/d10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_button_enabled_small"
            android:fontFamily="@font/texgyreheros_regular"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/d4dp"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/d14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/new_store_visit_scroll_view_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/new_store_visit_cv_top_card"
    android:overScrollMode="never">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/new_store_visit_cv_dashboard"
            layout="@layout/layout_sales_compare" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/new_store_visit_cv_checklist"
            layout="@layout/layout_store_visit_checklist"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<include
    android:id="@+id/new_store_visit_cv_help_pop_up"
    layout="@layout/layout_help_text_pop_up"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My store_visit_checklist_layout is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/d10dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/d8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/d8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d10dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/d8dp"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/store_visit_card_tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/texgyreheros_regular"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_default_card"
        android:text="@string/store_visit"
        android:textColor="@color/greyish_brown_two"
        android:textSize="@dimen/d14sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/store_visit_card_tv_clear_all"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/texgyreheros_regular"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_default_card"
        android:text="@string/clear_all"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/d12sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/store_visit_card_tv_title"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_default_card"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_default_card"
        android:background="@color/pinkish_grey" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/store_visit_card_rv_checklist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/store_visit_card_tv_title"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/d10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:itemCount="2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_store_visit_checklist" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My item_store_visit_checklist is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/d10dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_checklist">

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/item_store_visit_ib_dropdown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/d20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_default_card"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_default"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/d20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_grey" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/item_store_visit_tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/item_store_visit_ib_dropdown"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_store_visit_ib_dropdown"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/item_store_visit_ib_dropdown"
    android:fontFamily="@font/texgyreheros_regular"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="People Management"
    android:textColor="@color/greyish_brown"
    android:textSize="@dimen/d14sp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/item_store_visit_ib_help"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/item_store_visit_tv_title"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/d20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/d12dp"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/d12dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/d24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_help" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/item_store_visit_tv_comment_count"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/item_store_visit_iv_comments"
    android:fontFamily="@font/texgyreheros_regular"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/d14dp"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/d10dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/d14dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="@color/pinkish_grey"
    android:textSize="@dimen/d14sp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_store_visit_iv_comments"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/d20dp"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/d10dp"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/d10dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/d20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_empty" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_store_visit_ll_add_comment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_store_visit_ib_dropdown"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d0.5dp"
        android:background="@color/pinkish_grey" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/item_store_visit_et_add_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/d10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/d10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/d10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_add_comment"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/add_comment_hint"
        android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
        android:padding="@dimen/d10dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/d12sp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/item_store_visit_bt_add_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/d20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/d10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button_white_blue_stroke"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/d85dp"
        android:text="Add"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/d10sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/item_store_visit_rl_comments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/item_store_visit_ll_add_comment"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/d2dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/item_store_visit_rv_comments"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/item_store_visit_rv_comments"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/d8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/d10dp"
        android:background="@color/warm_grey_two_14" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/item_store_visit_rv_comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/d10dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        tools:itemCount="2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_store_visit_comment" />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem occurs when I click on the editText "item_store_visit_et_add_comment" it gets covered behind keyboard. I've tried setting adjustPan and adjustResize to my activity but nothing works.
What I want is, the editText should scroll so that it should be visible above keyboard.

For those who are tl;dr type, the layout is like:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <NestedScrollView>
        <layout1/>
        <layout2>
            <RecyclerView>
                <EditText/>
            </RecyclerView>
        </layout2>
    </NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```